# My Substitution Cipher is not combining the encrypted message in the StringBuilder

Tags: java, encryption

```
    //Fill Each Alphabet

    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i <alphabet.length; i++)
    {
        alphabetOriginal[i] = i;
        alphabet[i] = i;

        char letter = (char)(alphabetOriginal[i] + 65);

        if(alphabet[i] > 9)
            System.out.print(letter+ "  ");
        else
            System.out.print(letter+ " ");
    }

    //Switch each character!
    int position, temporary;
    Random rn = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i <alphabet.length; i++)
    {
        int j = rn.nextInt(26);

        temporary = alphabet[25-i];
        alphabet[25-i] = alphabet[j];
        alphabet[j] = temporary;
    }

    //Display the Scrambled Alphabet if they Are Interested
    if(validateAffirm(decision))
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n\tYou can see the (randomly generated) new alphabet below!\n");

        for(int i = 0; i <alphabet.length; i++)
            System.out.print(alphabet[i] + " ");

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
        {
            char ScrambleLetter = (char)(alphabet[i] + 65);

            if(alphabet[i] > 9)
                System.out.print(ScrambleLetter + "  ");
            else
                System.out.print(ScrambleLetter + " ");
        }
    }

    //Use a Binary Search to Determine the Length of Each
    StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder(initMessage.length());
    int temporaryCharValue;

    for(int i = 0; i<initMessage.length(); i++)
    {
        temporaryCharValue = (int)(initMessage.charAt(i));
        temporaryCharValue-=65;
        for(int j = 0; alphabet[j] != temporaryCharValue; j++)
        {
            if(alphabet[j] == temporaryCharValue)
            {
                temporaryCharValue+=65;
                char tempChar = (char)(temporaryCharValue);
                sb4.append(tempChar);
                System.out.println(tempChar);
                sb4.toString();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" +sb4);
```

Can you help find out why my String isn't compiling to determine the final encrypted message? The arrays are defined just fine, but in my nested for loop, I cannot seem to access the proper method for combining each translated character into the final String. I am not even sure if the method translates the characters properly... (This is my first year programming, I apologize for any obvious mistakes. I am a junior in high school).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You code is hard to understand, there are constants that I don't know where they came from... however, It seems to me that the loop you mention had a definition problem... I explain:

According to your algorithm, your invariant (or looping condition) is `alphabet[j] != temporaryCharValue` however, the inner sentence (the IF sentence) expects that `alphabet[j] == temporaryCharValue`, so when `lphabet[j] == temporaryCharValue` is TRUE, the loop returns (or stops) and the IF Sentence is never evaluated...